# How can i access function that was setup in node and call it on browser?

Tags: html, button

in browser -On button click i want to trigger function from node "**myFunction**"

i have tryed **browsify** but nothing happened.

tested on localhost (wamp) server, and it works ok

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Title</title>
    
    

</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Input the order of the matrix
        <br />
        
        <input type="text" maxlength="3" name="value" id='valuee' value='5'/>
            </p>
    

            <button id="myButton">Click me!</button>

            

</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

**index.js ( variant that works in Node Terminal )**

```
const fs = require('fs')
const express = require('express');


    

  function readDb(dbName = 'db.csv') {
    // read JSON object from file
    const data = fs.readFileSync(dbName, 'utf8')
    return JSON.parse(data)
}

function writeDb(obj, dbName = 'db.csv') {
    if (!obj) return console.log('Please provide data to save')
    try {
        fs.writeFileSync(dbName, JSON.stringify(obj))
        return console.log('SAVE SUCESS')
    } catch (err) {
        return console.log('FAILED TO WRITE')
    }
}


//function myFunction(){

  

  const dataObj = {james:'144114'}
    writeDb(dataObj)

    module.exports = { readDb, writeDb }
    console.log('You are on the browser');

    
//}
//else {
//   console.log('You are on the server');
//  }
```

If i uncomment **myFunction ( from above )** and do action in node: **browserify index.js >  bundle.js**

I``m getting `**`myFunction it`s not defined** in browser console when accesing localhost/index.html

Any solution?...thanks in advance

Comment: NodeJS runs on the server, not in the browser.  If you want to invoke server-side functionality from JavaScript in the browser then the technology you're looking for is "AJAX".  You'd use AJAX to make an HTTP request to an endpoint in your Node web server (probably Express?) and can perform your operations there.  (As an aside... There is no `window` in Node.  You seem to be very much confusing client-side code and server-side code, among a variety of other oddities in the code shown.)

Comment: browserify doesn`t help? thanks for your answer

Comment: I actually missed that part.  But no, it won't help in this case.  The answer below goes into more detail.  But many JavaScript modules are Node-only and won't work in a browser.  The browser and Node provide two different environments with different capabilities to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to the output of browserify.

> [ jdkfjskdfjdkfjkdjfkd ] ➜  npx browserify index.js > bundle.js
> Error: Can't walk dependency graph: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
> lstat '/REDACTED/jdkfjskdfjdkfjkdjfkd/async_hooks'
> required by /REDACTED/jdkfjskdfjdkfjkdjfkd/node_modules/on-finished/index.js

It is throwing an error and generating an **empty** *bundle.js* file.

---

The `fs` module is built into Node.js. It can't be bundled. It does things that browsers do not let JavaScript do. You can't run the code you've written in a browser.

The `express` module depends on features with the same restrictions and can't be bundled either.

(I'm not going to analyse `fpcalc` and `fast-csv` to see if they do too).

---

You aren't using `express` so you can just remove it from your script.

You could replace `fs` with an alternative (such as keeping data in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or loading files with `<input type="file">` and `FileReader` and writing them by generating `data:` scheme URLs and using `<a download href="data:...">`) and then your script might run in a browser.